# Dsiplay MongoDB Output result in JSP

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following query in MongoDB which returns a result.

```
 collection.find(eq("name", name)).forEach(printBlock);
```

How can I collect the results of the above query and pass it to JSP?

I would like if soemone could give an example on how to do this?

Thanks in advance